# How to detect KeyPress while program is running in background in Win32 C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++-2010

I got a program that whenever I minimize it, it goes to the system tray.

i want to know is this:
a) how could i detect a key press while my program is in the system tray.
b) how could I know what they press in the keyboard specifically the function buttons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set up a keyboard hook using [SetWindowsHookEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx). Look at the [WH_KEYBOARD and WH_KEYBOARD_LL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_keyboardhook) hooks.

Comment: Wow, this was voted down! I'm not bitter, just keen to know the reason why :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Raw Input to get [`WM_INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input) messages directly from the keyboard driver. Look at [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices).

Comment: after setting up the hook what's next?

Answer (score 10):

If you know exactly what keystroke you're expecting, you can use [`RegisterHotkey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Windows will send you a message when that key is pressed.

If you want to detect all keystrokes, @OJ's answer will work.