# C++ How to store user key press inside a variable

Tags: c++, winapi

So, I already know that by using `if (GetAsyncKeyState())` I can check if the user presses a specific key. But what I need is to check if the user presses any key and to store that key that the user pressed inside a variable. Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean like [GetKeyboardState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate)?  Also, typically in Windows applications, we register for windows events and handle WM_KEYDOWN.  Are you opposed to that?

Comment: I think we should remove the codeblocks tag from this question.  Any objection to that?

Comment: @Wyck.....Done....

Comment: @Wyck Anything will do as long as I can store it inside a variable.

Comment: Handle WM_KEYDOWN in your wndproc and store wParam in a variable as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

First, [_getch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160) could read a single character from the console without echoing the character. But it has limitations, it cannot read all keys.

Then, [`GetKeyboardState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate) can get the status of the 256 virtual keys. But it cannot detect the key event between two calls.

You could register key down event with [RawInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) or [LowLevelKeyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)), Check [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789990/10611792), you will get the [Virtual-Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) in `input.data.keyboard.VKey`. You could create a thread to wait and get the key event, instead of polling to check key status.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you're trying to get input without the user pressing 'Enter', in that case see [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/912184/5383406).